# How to validate the decomposed distributions?

Tags: distributions, modeling, simulation, discrete-distributions

I am fitting distributions for the time spent for three processes (i.e., pick up tools, walk to destination, install) in a system that I am trying to simulate where the original data for these processes are represented, in a data we pulled from the system, in time as "one process" (i.e., repair). The data for the three processes were collected from observations, and then distributions were fitted for each of the three processes. I am now in the phase of validating the distributions for these three processes to make sure they represent the "one process". That is, to make sure the three fitted distributions are an actual representation of the one process mentioned above.

I compared the simulation output (i.e., time) histogram of the sum of three processes with the one process for the shape, mean, max, & min, and thus to make sure we have similar output to our original data (based on "one process").

My question is: besides what I have done, what is the most accepted method(s) for validating the decomposed distributions?